Temporary tags for ID questions while awaiting the unblocking of ID tags
It has been nearly three months since our community voted to reinstate ID questions, and more than a month since we requested that the Community Managers unblacklist tags such as identify-this-movie and identify-this-tv-show. However, these tags remain unavailable for use, causing several issues:

Users cannot follow or be notified of new ID questions, as they are unable to add them to their "watched tags" list.
Those who prefer not to see ID questions cannot easily filter them out from their feed by adding them to the "ignored tags" list.
The lack of appropriate ID tags makes it harder to categorize and search for these questions.
We're currently using genre tags for ID questions, which may not be appropriate since the questions are not really about the genres themselves.

Given that the CM tag unblacklisting process might take several months (based on my past experiences in various SE sites), I suggest we implement a temporary solution. Here's what I propose:

Introduce temporary tags, e.g., movie-identification and tv-show-identification.
Use these tags for all new ID questions until the original tags are unblacklisted.
Once the Community Managers unblacklist identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, and the other ID tags, we can merge and synonymize the temporary tags to the main ones.

This approach would allow us to better organize ID questions in the short term and make the transition smoother when the original tags become available again. It would also improve the user experience for both those who want to see ID questions and those who prefer to avoid them.
What do you think about this temporary solution? Are there any potential drawbacks or alternatives we should consider? Let's discuss and find the best way to handle this situation while we wait for the official unblacklisting.

Seems reasonable to me.  I don't see much downside to doing this as we have good control over tag synonyms.

Excellent out of the box thinking...

I might remember incorrectly, but I think we actually did use genre tags for ID questions in the past (which doesn't necessarily mean it's a good idea, though).

As a stop-gap, I went with creating the "movie-identification" tag on a question I was just editing, but the edit reviewers may have a better idea.

I'd like to ask if using both of these tags would be appropriate when a user does not know if the show they're trying to identify was a movie or a TV show episode? I have been wondering for years about some dialogue samples used in a piece of music, and all the composer remembers is that he held a microphone up to his TV to catch those samples.

@AJM Using both tags makes sense to me if the user isn't sure whether it's a movie or a TV show.

@AJM I remember seeing such questions in the past, if enough detail was provided they worked fine with both tags.

I concur with adding temporary tags; it looks like Valorum has already created tv-show-identification and I just applied movie-identification to a question.
It's fast, it works, and they can easily be synonymized with the canonical (existing, older) tags once those are unblocked.

I'm full of those tricks ;-)

@Valorum ID tags have now been unblocked and we need to synonomize these new tags. I'm unsure which how tags are prioritised so that tag rep and answer counts etc is maintained on the old tags.

@Paulie_D My understanding is that by synonymizing [tag:movie-identification] with [tag:identify-this-movie], all points etc. earned for the temporary (synonym) tag will show up on the permanent tag.  Basically, all questions with the temporary tag get a virtual edit to the permanent tag.
